# Remove duplicate record in excel using java

Tags: java

I have a lot of data in an excel file which have a lot of duplicate rows I want to delete all of the duplicate rows and want to have a unique data in my excel file.  I have used this code but it sometimes removes not an entire duplicate row but some duplicate characters

```
Task 1 (2)  3/03/2017 23:27:0   C:\Users\Fa16Rcs028\Dropbox\Spring 17\Special Topics In HCI\Tasks\Task1\Task 1.tex
Task 1 (2)  3/03/2017 23:27:0   C:\Users\Fa16Rcs028\Dropbox\Spring 17\Special Topics In HCI\Tasks\Task1\Task 1.tex
Task 1 (2)  3/03/2017 23:27:0   D:\Users\Fa16Rcs028\Dropbox\Spring 17\Special Topics In HCI\Tasks\Task1\Task 1.tex
Task 1 (2)  3/03/2017 23:27:0   C:\Users\Fa16Rcs028\Dropbox\Spring 17\Special Topics In HCI\Tasks\Task1\Task 1.tex
Task 1 (2)  3/03/2017 23:27:0   C:\Users\Fa16Rcs028\Dropbox\Spring 17\Special Topics In HCI\Tasks\Task1\Task 1.tex
```

I want to remove all of these duplicates and just want unique records here. My piece of code is

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package removeduplicate;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;



/**
 * TODO To change the template for this generated type comment go to Window -
 * Preferences - Java - Code Style - Code Templates
 */
public class RemoveDuplicate {
 static String[]   tmp = new String[3];
 static int count=0;
     static String user=System.getProperty("user.name");

     static String path2="C:\\Users\\"+user+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\zeeshan.xls";

 public RemoveDuplicate() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    HSSFWorkbook workBook = null;
    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;
    fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(path2));
    workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    Set s=new HashSet();
    String str="";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        str="";
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow((short) i);
        int columns = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            HSSFCell cell0 = row.getCell((short) j);
            int type=cell0.getCellType();
            if(type==0)
            {
                double intValue= cell0.getNumericCellValue();
            str=str+String.valueOf(intValue)+",";
            }
            else if(type==1)
            {
                String stringValue=cell0.getStringCellValue();
                str=str+stringValue+",";
            }
        }

        str=str.replace(str.charAt(str.lastIndexOf(",")), ' ');
        s.add(str.trim());
    }
    String result="";
    Iterator iter=s.iterator();
    HSSFWorkbook workBookOut = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheetOut = workBookOut.createSheet("Final Sheet");
   HashMap<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
   while(iter.hasNext())
   {
        result=iter.next().toString();

        int i= result.indexOf("/");
        {   

            tmp[0]=result.substring(0,i-2);
            tmp[1]=result.substring(i-1,i+16);
            tmp[2]=result.substring(i+18);
            ++count;
            String rowcount=Integer.toString(count);
            data.put(rowcount, new Object[] {tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2]});

       }




   }
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset)
        {

            Row row = sheetOut.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr)
            {

               Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
               if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
            }
        }
     try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path2)) {
         workBookOut.write(fileOut);
     }

  }}
```

Comment: Can you share your sample file for test?